# filter + map api design

Tags: java, javascript, map, filtering

I am writing a library call that will allow you to filter and map in the same iteration of the loop, this is async/callback style in Java. The problem of course is that for filtering we usually return true/false, but for mapping we need to return the value we want.

So I am thinking of something like this:

```
(val, v) -> {
   v.include();   // we want to keep this value
   return val * 2;  // the value to map to
}
```

so the include() method call is like returning true in a typical filter operation. We could add an exclude() method which is returning false.

My question is - is this a good methodology? Are there libraries that do something like this that have a well-understood way of filtering and mapping in the same iteration?

if it's not clear, this would discard the element in the array.

```
(val, v) -> {
   v.exclude();   
   return null; 
}
```

another solution would be for them to return a unique key if they want to filter the value out:

```
(val, v) -> {
   return DISCARD_KEY;  // return a unique key representing discard, like returning false in a typical filter 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most functional programming languages or libraries, you would do this with a [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), and use an empty array (or option) if you want to exclude the item, like in JavaScript:

```js
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].flatMap(x => (x % 2 == 1) ? [] : x / 2)
// outputs [3, 4, 5]
```

This removes all the odd numbers and halves all the even numbers.

Comment: I believe it should be `[x / 2]`, unless JavaScript does some kind of type coercion in this case.

Comment: It does coerce, but you're right that would be technically more correct.

Comment: so the empty array represents false (filter it out)? Not sure I get it...what if the input array was made up of arrays?

Comment: @MrCholo: `flatMap` maps elements to arrays, then flattens these arrays, where an empty array is flattened to nothing. Think of `flatMap` as a more general version of `map`, in that it can return 0 to N elements, instead of exactly 1 like `map`.

Comment: you said `use an empty array (or option) if you want to exclude the item` - what do you mean by option?

Comment: An option is a type in some libraries that indicates either the presence or absence of a value. For example, [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) in Java.

Comment: so something like `return new Optional<>()`  (would essentially return false) and `return new Optional<>(someValue)` would represent true, and the value to be mapped to would be someValue? is that about right?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Java, but I think you would want `Optional.empty` when you want to omit the item, and `Optional.of` to include it.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt thanks, your `java.util.Optional` idea was a good one and worked for me, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Using Java, I decided to use the `java.util.Optional` type, which is essentially a wrapper for a value or an absence of a value. If you use this:

`Optional.empty()`, it's the absence of a value, which means false in our filter scheme.

otherwise I use:

`Optional.of(v)`, where that means `true` in our filter scheme and the mapped value is v. So the implementation looks something like:

```
public void done(E e, Optional<T> o) {
  if (o != null && o.isPresent()) {
    this.done(e, o.get());  
  } else {
    this.discard();
    this.done(e, (T) DISCARD_KEY);
  }
}
```

note that the `java.util.Optional` wrapper concept could be implemented in literally any language, it's not unique to Java, which is why this answer is pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this pattern creates some ambiguity. What should the result be, for instance, if the caller does not call either `include()` OR `exclude()`? There is no chance to catch this situation statically, so either you have to deal with this ambiguity in your library or throw a runtime exception.

As a suggestion, why not make the return value of the callback an action defining what to do with the element?

If we call what you want to do a Milter (Map + Filter), you might end up with something like this (Don't have a compiler here so this may not be picture-perfect):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Milter.Visitor<Integer> visitor = new Milter.Visitor<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public MilterAction<Integer> visit(Integer element) {
                if (element % 2 == 0) {
                    return MilterAction.exclude();
                } else {
                    return MilterAction.include(element + 2);
                }
            }
        };

        Milter<Integer> oddsPlus2Milter = new Milter<Integer>(visitor);

        List<Integer> sourceList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

        oddsPlus2Milter.run(sourceList).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

class Milter<T> {
    public interface Visitor<I> {
        MilterAction<I> visit(I element);
    }

    private Visitor<T> visitor;

    Milter (Visitor<T> visitor) {
        this.visitor = visitor;
    }

    List<T> run(List<T> source) {
        List<T> milteredResult = new ArrayList<T>();
        source.forEach(element -> {
            MilterAction<T> visitResult = this.visitor.visit(element);
            if (visitResult.shouldInclude()) {
                milteredResult.add(visitResult.getValue());
            }
        });

        return milteredResult;
    }
}

class MilterAction<T> {
    public static <I> MilterAction<I> include(I value) {
        return new MilterAction<I>(FilterAction.INCLUDE, value);
    }

    public static <I> MilterAction<I> exclude() {
        return new MilterAction<I>(FilterAction.EXCLUDE, null);
    }

    public enum FilterAction {
        INCLUDE,
        EXCLUDE
    }

    private FilterAction action;
    private T value;

    MilterAction(FilterAction action, T value) {
        this.action = action;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean shouldInclude() {
        return this.action.equals(FilterAction.INCLUDE);
    }
}
```

This way, your compiler can ensure for you that all consumer's of the Milter class provide it with a visitor that always returns an appropriate action.

Comment: well the default return value is true, meaning by default it would be included?

Comment: When you say default return value, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, how do you assign a lambda/Runnable/method reference a "default return value"?

Answer (score 0):

Java has the `Optional::stream` function, and streams have `flatMap`. These two together will let you write java code that is very similar to the JavaScript code in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/387859/3307

```
values.stream()
      .flatMap( v -> (include(v) ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(v*2)).stream() )
```